# Iterating specific values from a json response with Python

Tags: python, json, curl

I am receiving a python dict that has the following format via curl.

```
json = connect(header, URL)
```

[python dict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8T5D.png)

I am trying to iterate/get the different "number" values with the following code:

```
for i in json['mail']['number']: 

    print (str(i).replace('"',''))
```

but it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please copy paste you dict, so we can easily figure out what's going wrong

Comment: Share some part of dictionary in your code

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over the wrong object, try this:

```py
for i in json['mail']:
    print(int(i['number']))
```

Please also note: naming a variable `json` could be very bad because most likely you are using the `json` package as well and this will lead to naming conflicts.